# OIDC dynamically register SpringBoot Client application

Tags: spring-boot, okta

How do I do OIDC dynamic client registration for a spring boot 2.1 app?
https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oauth-clients/

Does Spring Security provide a means to register on startup and get back the clientId and clientSecret?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security does not provide a registration API.

You *could* register a new client in an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` (or similar mechanism), where your custom code would register the client and then set the required OAuth properties.

With Okta you would need an API key to make this request:
https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oauth-clients/#register-new-client

Does that help?